# Check whether string contains fragment in Tcl

Tags: string, tcl

I have a set of words, e.g. {6-31G*, 6-311G*, 6-31++G*, 6-311++G**}. As you may see, the common fragment is "6-31". What I need to do in Tcl now is to check whether string under `$variable` contains this fragment. I know I could do it with regular expression like this:

```
if {[regexp {^6-31} $variable]} {
  puts "You provided Pople-style basis set"
}
```

but what other solution could I use (just out of curiosity)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just to check if a string contains a particular substring, I'd use [`string first`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M8)

```
set substring "6-31"
if {[string first $substring $variable] != -1} {
    puts "\"$substring\" found in \"$variable\""
}
```

You can also use glob-matching with `string match` or `switch`

```
switch -glob -- $variable {
    *$substring* {puts "found"}
    default      {puts "not found"}
}
```